# Oracle database mirroring

Tags: database, oracle, database-administration

We have ERP application that store the data to ORACLE database. And also we have a lot of another application that use the ERP database. Same database but different instances. We got the performance issues when ERP and another application use the same database.

We are planning to separate the database server become three. One for ERP and two others for report and applications. these new database servers are came from ERP database, because they use the same database structure and data. So we could say these new database servers are mirror of ERP database. And also sometime data on the mirror database could be updated by other application, and it should be also updated on ERP database.

What best practice and method should be used for mirroring this condition?
Is it enough by use Data guard from ORACLE?

This is the picture of the architecture plan.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Data guard does not allow writing to the stand-by. Active dataguard does allow reading from the stand-by while archiving transactions from the primary node. So the report server using your ERP Mirror 1 is not a problem as long as it only reads data. Writing from the other applications to ERP Mirror 2 is. What you are looking for is advanced replication or Oracle streams. This is a very complex task. Maybe offloading your reporting to a data-guard stand-by solves your problems.